# Trying to use dask delayed to read and count rows in csv files

Tags: python, delay, dask

I have 5 CSV files containing approx 1M records each. I'm using dask to try to read them in a parallel way, and counting the records in each one , then summing to get the total count of records.
Here is my code:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask

counts = []

def read_file(fn):
    df = dask.delayed(dd.read_csv)(fn)
    return len(df.index)

for i in range(5):
    filename="c://parallel//test"+str(i)+".csv"
    print(filename)
    counts.append(read_file(filename))
    

dask.compute(sum(counts))
```

However I receive the following error message when attempting to run the above code.

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\delayed.py in __len__(self)
    549     def __len__(self):
    550         if getattr(self, "_length", None) is None:
--> 551             raise TypeError("Delayed objects of unspecified length have no len()")
    552         return self._length
    553 

TypeError: Delayed objects of unspecified length have no len()
```

If I replace the line `return len(df.index)` with a hard-coded value such as `return 1000` everything works as expected

Can anyone show me how to get around this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Do not mix collections (dataframe) within delayed functions.
The solution you are looking for should be simpler:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

filenames = ["c://parallel//test"+str(i)+".csv" for i in range(5)]
df = dd.read_csv(filenames)
len(df)
```